# Using generated SSL key with KeyStore

Tags: java, android, ssl

I understand how to load a key from a file into a `KeyStore` so that I can pass it to a `KeyManager` and ultimately to `SSLContext` so that I can use the key as my client-side SSL certificate (as explained in [this article](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/https-with-client-certificates-on/)).

I would like my app to generate and keep its own unique client certificate when it is first run.  I am able to successfully use `generateKeyPair()` to get a `KeyPair`, but I'm stuck trying to import it into a `KeyStore`.  (`SingleKeyManager` is a class I wrote.)

```
    KeyPair keyPair = new SingleKeyManager().getKey();
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS8");
```

Am I on the right track?  What's the best way to do what I want to accomplish?  Note that I'm not picky about the actual format of the key.

Comment: Er, KeyStore.setKeyEntry()?

Comment: What do I use for the key and the chain?